# Can you specify TLS v1.3 only in phpmailer?

Tags: phpmailer, starttls, sslv3, tls1.3

Is it possible to specify the encryption protocol version used in PHPMailer?

Trying to build a small web tool for testing SMTP configurations. I used to be able to specify protocol version in .NET, but now that I am using apache, I am trying to do it in a PHP page with phpmailer. So I need to have it try ONLY a single encryption version like TLS 1.3.

I know I can set the smtpautoTLS to FALSE. But Can I specify TLS 1.3 or SSL v3 in something like the SMTPOptions Array? I haven't seemed to be able to find this in documentation/examples/google.

Thanks!

*Edit for updated code and confirm this code only works for SMTPS/implicit style, but NOT STARTTLS*

```
<?php
    require_once 'PHPMailer/vendor/autoload.php';
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
    
    $from = $_POST['from'];
    $to = $_POST['to'];
    $subj = $_POST['subj'];
    $body = $_POST['body'];
    $server = $_POST['addr'];
    $port = $_POST['port'];
    $auth = $_POST['auth'];
    $enctype = $_POST['enctype'];
    $encver = $_POST['encver'];
    $authuser = $_POST['authuser'];
    $authpw = $_POST['authpw'];
    
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; //2 for debugging with server responses. 0-4 as choices
    
    $smtpopts = array();
    
    if($encver == "auto")
    {
        $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = true;
    }
    else
    {
        $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
    }
    
    if($auth == 1)
    {
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = $authuser;
        $mail->Password = $authpw;
        
        switch($enctype)
        {
            case "implicit":
                $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;
                break;
            case "explicit":
                $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
                break;
        }
        
        switch($encver)
        {
            case "ssl3_0":
                $smtpopts['ssl'] = array('crypto_method'  => STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_SSLv3_CLIENT);
                break;
            
            case "tls1_0":
                $smtpopts['ssl'] = array('crypto_method'  => STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_0_CLIENT);
                break;
            
            case "tls1_1":
                $smtpopts['ssl'] = array('crypto_method'  => STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_1_CLIENT);
                break;
                
            case "tls1_2":
                $smtpopts['ssl'] = array('crypto_method'  => STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT);
                break;
            
            case "tls1_3":
                $smtpopts['ssl'] = array('crypto_method'  => STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_3_CLIENT);
                break;
        }
    
        $mail->SMTPOptions = $smtpopts;
    }
    else
    {
        $mail->SMTPAuth = false;
    }
    
    $mail->Host = $server;
    $mail->Port = $port;
    
    $mail->SetFrom($from);
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    $mail->Subject = $subj;
    $mail->MsgHTML($body);
    
    $response = array();
    
    try
    {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $mail->Send();
        $response['success'] = 1;
        $response['msg'] = "Success";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        $response['success'] = 0;
        $response['msg'] = $e->errorMessage();
        error_log($e->errorMessage());
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        $response['success'] = -99;
        $response['msg'] = $e->getMessage();
        error_log($e->getMessage());
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The critical constant for TLSv1.3 support is `STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_3_CLIENT`, which was [introduced in PHP 7.4.0](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/5c05f5e6d3d31a03c152fe90697bdc3e33193ced), but appears to be undocumented.

PHPMailer uses the TLS constant `STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT` [in the SMTP class when encryption is initialised via STARTTLS](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/src/SMTP.php#L430). This constant combines TLS 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, and 1.3, as you can see [in the PHP source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.4.0/main/streams/php_stream_transport.h#L176).

So, for your particular situation, you want to substitute the `STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT` default for `STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_3_CLIENT`. You can achieve what you ask (at least for testing purposes) by subclassing the SMTP class and overriding the `startTLS` method so that you can control the TLS constant.

However, that approach will only work for SMTP+STARTTLS, not SMTPS. For SMTPS (`ssl` mode in PHPMailer) you can use a different approach that may work for both. Looking at [this test case](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/20664d602389c09ce42ad03d4a6e071d32c0f329/ext/openssl/tests/streams_crypto_method.phpt#L40) shows that you can specify a connection type constant in the options passed to `stream_context_create` – and this is the exact same array that PHPMailer gives you access to, so try this:

```php
$mail->SMTPOptions = [
    'ssl' => ['crypto_method' => STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_3_CLIENT]
];
```

Comment: I am not sure if adjusting the crypto_method is working. I tested it with AWS SES, which I believe should not support SSL 3.0, but it seems to go through. I will see if I can test it with office 365 SMTP. I added my code in case the mistake is easy to spot.

Comment: One thing to bear in mind is that it's extremely common to use relatively low security settings on mail servers, because failing to negotiate a secure connection may end in clear-text transmission, which is worse than having no encryption at all, no matter how bad it might be. This applies more to inbound than outbound though.

Comment: I can confirm with my .NET code that controlling the encryption protocol works as intended by failing AWS SES emails when using SSL v3, but allows the supported protocols.

I also tested and your solution for using the SSL mode in the options seems to only work on the SMTPS. I will have to see if your first part of the solution will allow me to manipulate STARTTLS, as that is the sticking point as well as the most commonly used